# unable to success through json...curser is not going try block

Tags: android, android-json

I'm letting users retrieve their forgotten password  **by webservice**. all are function is performing  `json` give success output  but after this  debugger is not going in try (if else) condition...

**my forgetpass response:**

```
{
status: "Success" 
msg: "Password has been sent your Email_id , Please check it.."
}
```

**try/catch:**

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",Email));

JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);
Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
try{
    String status=json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
    if(status=="TAG_SUCCESS"){

        Toast.makeText(ForgetPassWord.this,"Password has been sent your Email_id , Please check it..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(ForgetPassWord.this,"Please Enter Correct E-Mail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}catch(JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `equals()` for **String Comparison**

like

```
status.equals("Success")
```

Edit:

Change it like below

```
  private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="status";// Because  status is the key

String status = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: thnks for help amit ...but still not working....String status=json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);.aftr this statement debuggr move on (catch)....

Comment: @user3596211 did you get the response successfully. What is the value for "TAG_SUCCESS" that you define. Json key always be case sensitive.

Comment: i m getting response successfully from json  

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="Success";.......this is define in class .........

Comment: @user3596211 TAG_SUCCESS="Success"; this is wrong. b'coz the key string is "status". Check my updated answer.

Comment: thnku so much amit bro  ...its working ..aftr this how to send email to given email andress.......plzzz tell me about how to code plzzz

Comment: @user3596211 if its working for you, please accept my answer. And create a new thread for new question.

Comment: aftr successing toast msg is not displaying in this .....getting error unfortunatally app has stoped ....error

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
try {

            if (json.has((TAG_SUCCESS))) {
                String status = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (status.equals(TAG_SUCCESS)) {

                    Toast.makeText(
                            ForgetPassWord.this,
                            "Password has been sent your Email_id , Please check it..",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(ForgetPassWord.this,
                            "Please Enter Correct E-Mail",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: if (status.equals("Success")

this is correct .....and big thnxx to you(AMIT) for solving my prob

Comment: Declare this to above                                           private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="Success";